# Remove leading slash from URLs in Excel file

Tags: excel

I have a large Excel file with 5000 URL's in them. I need to remove the leading slash from the beginning of the URLs. Obviously I don't want to have to go and remove all 5000 of the leading slashes so I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

Here is a picture explaining my issue a bit more in depth.
This image explains my problem in depth.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have you tried anything already? VBA, macro's or something else? Please show it to us.

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm not very good with macro's or VBAs. I've seen a couple of things that are similar to what I need but not exactly what I need, and I don't know how to customize the macro or VBA to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula to strip the leading character out.

Assuming the Column you have your URLs in is `Column C`

1. Create a new Column to the right of the column with the URL.
2. In the function bar, enter the following formula `=RIGHT(C1, LEN(C1)-1)`
   [image]
3. Fill the rest of the `Column D` with this formula and it will update all of the rows
   in `Column D` with the modified URLs.

After you are done and satisfied the URLs are in the form you need, you can delete the original column.

Comment: No problem! If you continue to work with comma or tab separated files in this way, I would highly recommend picking up some Python. Doing this was easy, but more complex manipulations can be easily done with Python and it's built in CSV reader.

Comment: Great to know! I will definitely look into this.